# Apache Hue Port Forward from Virtual Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, vagrant, cloudera, hue

I am using Apache Hue to manage a virtual Hadoop cluster.  The virtual cluster is created using Vagrant and installs the Cloudera management tools.  The setup is 1 master, 3 slaves, and 1 client with the client running the Hue server.

Via the Vagrant File have port 7180 forwarding from the master to localhost (NAT Network) - so I am able access the manager at localhost:7180 - piece of cake.

On the client I have port 8888 (Hue, NAT Network) forwarding to localhost via the Vagrant File.  I am still only able to access Hue via the VM's IP (Host Only Network) or the hostname (added to the hostname file).

Is another configuration step required to get the Hue server listening on the correct port or to the correct address?

Host is OS X, Guest is Ubuntu Precise, Manager is Cloudera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can enable access from outside the VM by changing a configuration
>   in Cloudera Manager. Go to Services -> Hue -> Configuration -> View
>   and Edit -> Hue Server -> Ports and Addresses and check "Bind Hue
>   Server to Wildcard Address". You will need to restart the Hue service,
>   but should then be able to access port 8888 from your host machine.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/scm-users/31zh4rrlP2g/NAUIjBF4gZsJ)